# SQL - Finding duplicates based on 3 columns with different data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL noob here, let me know if I'm not wording anything right. I'm trying to find all entries where there is more than one instance of the same data in 3 columns. Below is some sample data from the 3 columns.

```
formatid    type_from            call_desc_code
20          002694W0:USAGE       V9
20          013030W0:USAGE       OM
20          013030W0:USAGE       NULL
```

From what I understand checksum can be used for this but the output from the below query doesn't seem right. The first part of the query that I'm putting into the #temp table has 29824 results which tells me there should be only 29824 unique combinations of the 3 columns but when I've run the full query then tried removing duplicates in Excel based on only those 3 columns to sanity check the results I have a whole lot more then 29824 entries left.

The formatid is a smallint data type so when I've tried just concatenating the cells with + it returns a conversion failed error. I'm running SQL Server 2012 but I don't think the database is on the same as it doesn't recognise the concat function.

```
select checksum(formatid,type_from,call_desc_code) & checksum(reverse(formatid),reverse(type_from),reverse(call_desc_code)) as [checksum], count(*) as [Blah]
into #temp
from Table
group by checksum(formatid,type_from,call_desc_code) & checksum(reverse(formatid),reverse(type_from),reverse(call_desc_code))
having count(*) > 1

select * from
Table
where checksum(formatid,type_from,call_desc_code) & checksum(reverse(formatid),reverse(type_from),reverse(call_desc_code)) in (select [checksum] from #temp)
drop table #temp
```

Comment: ...Do you just mean you want rows where those 3 columns are unique?

Comment: Duplicates where there is the same data in all 3 columns, G B's answer has done it I think.

Comment: @Harrisson, if answer helped you, accept it to close out the question.

Comment: @Harrisson `DISTINCT` would be simpler and shorter, if there are no other result columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will get you everything from your source table which has duplicates

```
select *
from table t
inner join 
        (select formatid,type_from,call_desc_code
        from Table
        group by formatid,type_from,call_desc_code
        having count(*) > 1) dup
    on dup.formatid = t.formatid
    and dup.type_from = t.type_from
    and dup.call_desc_code = t.call_desc_code
```